# How to sort table using PhP $PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have the following function defined to create a html table using the data fetched from the database. I dont know how to use a new variable $orderby to order the results from the table as using ORDER BY `firstname`. I tried to do it several times and i failed. Any ideas?

```
function htmlTable( $pdo, $table, $orderby) {


 $sql = "DESCRIBE `".$table."`";
    $stmt = $pdo->query( $sql);


    print "<table>";
    print "<tr>";
    foreach( $stmt as $v) {
        print "<th>".$v['Field']."</th>";
    }
    print "</tr>";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."`";
    // specify only an associative array to be returned
    $stmt = $pdo->query( $sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach( $stmt as $row) {
        print "<tr>";
        foreach( $row as $v) {

            print "<td>".$v."</td>";

        }
        print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
}
```

Comment: so, where and how is `$orderby` defined?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY $orderby` ??

Comment: I guess order by should be ASC or DESC ```SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY firstname $orderby```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: and consider trying better approach like https://phpbestpractices.org/#mysql

Comment: Not tested, but should be something like this:  `$orderby = " ORDER BY " + $myColumnName;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$table."`" + $orderby;`

Comment: `+ $orderby` @Marco the `+` is for JS/C syntax concatenation. In PHP, it's a dot.

Comment: [*"My actual problem is not the order by code SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY firstname"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333670/how-to-sort-table-using-php-pdo#comment81619213_47333844) - I love this comment, you have to wonder even more as to what the question is about. Oh yeah: *"I dont know how to use a new variable $orderby to order the results from the table as using ORDER BY firstname"*.

Comment: @Fred -ii You're right, in PHP concatenation is with a dot, Java guy here. Sorry about that :)

Comment: no need to edit your title with SOLVED, accepting an answer does that. I rolled it back. Next time, take my advice [from the comment I left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333670/how-to-sort-table-using-php-pdo#comment81618631_47333670). That did solve your question yet you said nothing.

Comment: @Marco no worries ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys for sharing your thoughts on this. Even the negative ones. I dont know much about $pdo and creating queries using php. This was the reason why i wanted some clearance on how to do it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for pointing some things out. I`m new to stackoverflow so please excuse my mistakes. I dont want to upset anyone until i get the hang of how things work around here. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: It feels like it's a lazy student question...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's so simple that it seems like it's a lazy student question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add that variable to your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table} {$orderby};";
```

read more about basic sql query structure:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: i have looked over w3c. My actual problem is not the order by code SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY `firstname`;   the problem is that i dont know how to create a query inside that function to execute the query and display it in the html table. Sorry if i dont make any sense, im still new using $pdo in php.

Comment: @Sorin Hampu You are using PHP, so you need to refresh the page to see the "new" table, then i am not wrong.